# What would be equivalent to JavaScript promise.all() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In JavaScript we can run functions in parallel using promise.all() but it doesn't exist in python, how can I run two functions in parallel in Python?

```
import discord
import asyncio                          
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print("Monitor Ativo!")
 promise.start()
async def bar():                                                                       
 print("sjj")                                                                                                                                   

async def ba():                                                                      
 print("dhhdh")                                                                                                           

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def promise():                             
 await asyncio.wait([bar(), ba()])
```

But I noticed that when I run the function it always runs the last function first, so it can't be running in parallel right?

Since it's always running the last function before the first one, so it has a pattern, and so it can't be running in parallel, how can I run two functions in parallel in python, equivalent to promise.all in javascript.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for what you are actually asking about. The code as shown has multiple issues wrt concurrency – it doesn't run anything, and if it would it wouldn't have any concurrent parts. Note also that ``asyncio`` is a tool for multi-tasking, not for parallelism.

Comment: You might want to look into multithreading and running each function in its own thread. Here's a [threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I already edited

Comment: @VoidTwo I already edited

Comment: Just to clarify, JavaScript is single threaded… the promises are not run in parallel in the sense that they may both be executing simultaneously on different cpu cores, but they may be able to yield the cpu to another promise while they wait for some event to occur. This is already basically the same as the way asyncio works in Python. With that in mind, could you clarify your question? If you could give some example JavaScript code that you would want to implement in Python that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.create_task`.

Code:

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def bar():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("sjj")


async def ba():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("dhhdh")


async def promise():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(bar()), asyncio.create_task(ba())]
    for task in tasks:
        await task

asyncio.run(promise())
```

Answer (score 3):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027026/12101554) by [@KetZoomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13710015/ketzoomer) works good, but here's how to scale easier with a syntax closer to what you wanted and properly return the return values:

```py
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def bar():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print(f"bar\ttotal time elapsed: {time.time() - start_time}s")
    return 5


async def ba():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"ba\ttotal time elapsed: {time.time() - start_time}s")
    return 19

async def b(num):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print(f"b\ttotal time elapsed: {time.time() - start_time}s\tyour number was {num}")
    return 2000


async def promise_all(funcs):
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(func()) for func in funcs]
    return [await task for task in tasks]

print(asyncio.run(promise_all([bar, ba, lambda: b(5)])))
```

If you run this script, you'll see the output is (specific decimals might change, `bar` vs `b` might change):

```bash
$ py -3 banana.py
ba  total time elapsed: 3.002803325653076s
bar total time elapsed: 10.00796914100647s
b   total time elapsed: 10.00804877281189s  your number was 5
Output: [5, 19, 2000]
```

Note: as you can see by the last function (the `b` function), if you want to pass in a variable, use a lambda.

Comment: This considers only the call, in js promise all returns the return of the functions. What would be a good way to solve it?

Comment: @SoyCésarMora updated the answer to support multiple return values